# What is the time format like 01d15614cbaee92c in Windows Hotfixes?

Tags: windows, wmic, hotfix

The timestamp (`InstalledOn`) format of Windows Hotfixes' is not regularity it is showing various types like `MM-DD-YYYY`, `YYYY/MM/DD`, `YYYYMMDD` and `01d15614cbaee92c`.

These values can be obtained from `Win32_QuickFixEngineering` of `WMIC`.

I would like to know what is a timestamp like `01d15614cbaee92c` and how to parse it.

**Example data:**

```
Update KB955484 10cd4bf3009a2541
Update KB971512 01cd35e8c07bdeb1
Security Update KB2079403 01cd04587fa78c94
Security Update KB3109094 01d15614cbaee92c
```

thank you.

Comment: Do you have any 16-digit hex strings whose date-and-time equivalents you know?

Comment: @Scott Thanks your comment. I had no information about this format and equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this.

I think the hex values are [FILETIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime)s, in 64-bit hex representation.

A filetime is

> a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)

Microsoft refers to these 100-nanosecond units as [ticks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8).

Here is a JavaScript function which will convert one of those strings to a JavaScript date, which can you then [format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Getter) in any way you desire. In the example, the console log will display the date in [ISO 8601 format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

```js
const getDateFromHexTicks = hex => {
  const ticks = BigInt(`0x${hex}`);
  const ticksPerMs = BigInt(1e4);
  const ms = ticks / ticksPerMs;
  const fileTimeEpochOffset = BigInt(new Date('1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z').getTime());
  const unixTime = Number(ms + fileTimeEpochOffset);
  const date = new Date(unixTime);
  return date;
};

const date = getDateFromHexTicks('01d15614cbaee92c');
console.log(date.toISOString()); // 2016-01-23T19:32:28.702Z
```

Referring to the last line in your example data:

```
Security Update KB3109094 01d15614cbaee92c
```

indicates that this update was installed at `2016-01-23T19:32:28.702Z`

Comment: you just need to run `[datetime]::FromFileTime(0x01d15614cbaee92c)` in PowerShell which gives "Sunday, January 24, 2016 2:32:28 AM" (or whatever format you choose)

Comment: oh... awesome...

Comment: @phuclv That's good to know. I was not at a computer with PowerShell when I answered this. The solution above should work in any browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Oops. It is not a solution. Sorry my mistake.

1. convert `01d15614cbaee92c` to decimal: `130980511487027500`
2. remove last 5 numbers: `1309805114870` (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765637/convert-hexadecimal-value-to-timestamp-date-and-time)
3. devide by 1,000 and round up: `1309805115`
4. convert to unix(epoch) time: `1309805115` is equivalent to `07/04/2011 @ 6:45pm`(UTC), `2011-07-04T18:45:15+00:00`(ISO 8601)

but, `KB3109094` was released on 12/05/2015 it is not possible for it to have a timestamp of July 4th 2011. (thanks, @Ramhound)

Comment: `KB3109094` was released on 12/05/2015 it is not possible for it to have a timestamp  of July 4th 2011.